# Mapping Array to Interface Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapping

I am working with typescript in React. I have an array of Tag objects each with a name and id property. I am trying to map these tags to a new Select Item interface which has properties name and value.

My code:

```
let items: ISelectItem[];
        switch (this.state.selectedType) {
            case "Tag":{
               items = tags.map(tag => {
                   return {
                    name: tag.name, 
                    value: tag.id
                   }
                });
            }
            default: {
                items = [];
            }
        }
```

I am console.logging the items array and upon debugging it seems that I am hitting the correct switch case, however at the end my new items array is empty. What am I doing wrong with my mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning or breaking after your initial case so your default case is always running.

Add a `break;` statement at the end of the first case.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. Thank you!